# Method parameter annotations access

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

It took me a while to figure out that I was not making a mistake in annotating my method parameters.

But I am still not sure why, in the following code example, the way no. 1 does not work:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class AnnotationTest {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface MyAnnotation {
        String name() default "";
        }

    public void myMethod(@MyAnnotation(name = "test") String st) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Class<AnnotationTest> clazz = AnnotationTest.class;
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("myMethod", String.class);

        /* Way no. 1 does not work*/
        Class<?> c1 = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = c1.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println("1) " + method.getName() + ":" + myAnnotation);

        /* Way no. 2 works */
        Annotation[][] paramAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        System.out.println("2) " + method.getName() + ":" + paramAnnotations[0][0]);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
    1) myMethod:null
    2) myMethod:@AnnotationTest$MyAnnotation(name=test)
```

Is it just a flaw in the annotation imnplementation in Java?
Or is there a logical reason why the class array returned by `Method.getParameterTypes()` does not hold the parameter annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a flaw in the implementation.

A call to `Method#getParameterTypes()` returns an array of the parameters' types, meaning their classes.  When you get the annotation of that class, you are getting the annotation of `String` rather than of the method parameter itself, and `String` has no annotations ([view source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Must be a permanent point of programmers failure. ;-)